# Would very short correct answers be better left as comments?

Tags: discussion, answers, comments

While reviewing the low quality answer queue today I ran across several answers that were flagged for deletion with the reason that they were actually comments on the question. While all of these answers were *very* short, they *did* answer the question, but were flagged for deletion due to "does not appear to answer the question".

Examples from today's queue include:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/4777299
https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/4777328
https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/4777234

Note that two of those cases, the OP themselves actually returned and posted the answer to their question as an answer, and it was flagged for deletion.

I'm not arguing that the answers were particularly high quality, but I don't think they really met the bar for deletion. At the same time, I often struggle with that to do when I leave a helpful comment, and the OP comes back with "wow that solved my problem." Do I post a short answer so the question can be marked answered, or just leave the comment alone?

Where exactly should we draw the line between answering the question in a comment vs. answering the question with a very short answer?

Comment: "the answer to why my screen won't refresh is" ... "This does not provide an answer to the question."

Answer (score 15):

[The answer is simple: if it answers the question, it qualifies as an answer.](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/SelfDemonstratingArticle)

Comment: By linking a TV Tropes article, you just increased the time it takes to read your answer from 10 seconds to two hours.

Comment: @Robert Harvey: http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/SubvertedTrope

Comment: Ah, that explains a few things.

Answer (score 7):

I don't think you should ever use comments to post answers, no matter how short they are.

If you want to help the OP or the community out by pointing him in the right direction in a comment, that's certainly a perfectly OK thing to do.  That's all these "answers" really do anyway.

Deletion is typically reserved for things that are harmful to the site in some way, things that are contrary to the way the site works, or things that simply don't add any value.  If it's an answer, it's an answer.  If it's a bad answer, a downvote would seem to be appropriate.

Deciding whether these things have enough value to stick around or not is the reason we have review queues and moderator flags.