# New question, one line answer.. comment on it or answer it?

Tags: discussion

I get confused. Cause I saw some people commented the answer rather writing it on answer box.

Comment: Related: [Question with no answers, but issue solved in the comments](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251597/464709).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When only a one line answer is needed it's a strong sign that the question or answer isn't of high quality.

---

Consider whether the question should be closed/improved, or whether the answer you are considering posting is not actually a quality, complete, answer.

If you're *really* sure that the question is a quality, appropriate question, and that your answer is a quality, complete answer, and there simply isn't anything else to say, then post your answer as an answer.

Generally when you see such an answer posted as a comment it is because the comment author recognizes that the "answer" isn't complete, it's just a start.  They are either planning to expand on the answer and eventually post a real answer, or they just want someone else to take the time of writing a proper answer.

Comment: Not sure if self-demonstrating.

Comment: Couldn't help myself ;)  I had to cut out about half of my first draft to get it to one line.

Comment: ... forgot I did the exact same thing just a few days ago. *And* lampshaded it. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254296/would-very-short-correct-answers-be-better-left-as-comments/254299#254299