# Why was this answer deleted?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers, specific-answer

https://stackoverflow.com/a/25380698/298661

This is a perfectly fine, totally accurate answer. Why on Earth was it deleted by the moderator?

[image]

Comment: Add pic (or link to one) for us commoners unable to see deleted stuff.

Comment: The answer text is simply "No!". You believe a high quality answer like that should remain? In particular when the OP had to resort to Unicode trickery to go over the minimum post length restriction?

Comment: @Oded based on the question, yes. 'No!' perfectly answers the question. The question here is, is why is that question still around?

Comment: @Oded: There is nothing more to be said on the matter. The question is a very simple yes/no question.

Comment: @Puppy, any reason why you keep rolling back efforts by others to add a screenshot of that answer?

Comment: Then perhaps the question should be suspect?

Comment: @Oded: i see no reason why it's inherently invalid.

Comment: @thecoshman The pic is in [the revision history](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/269297/2).

Comment: Because I choose not to include a picture. If you want a picture, post it as a comment.

Comment: And the community is finding it more helpful to have the picture. Please don't get into a rollback war.

Comment: If you need to circumvent the length filter to post an answer; it's probably a sign that you shouldn't post the answer.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker [A previous discussion states that an answer is an answer regardless of how short it is](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254296/would-very-short-correct-answers-be-better-left-as-comments). Is this no longer true?

Comment: @Puppy [In that case, Stack Overflow may not be the site for you.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/editing) This was a valid edit (see reasons "To add related resources or hyperlinks" and "To include additional information only found in comments, so all of the information relevant to the post is contained in one place")

Comment: @Michelle: Because if the devs wanted people under 10k to participate in discussions about deleted content, they would not have programmed the site to hide that content from them. If I'm gonna give the site's owners the middle finger and circumvent their programmed, intentional restrictions, I'd at least like to do so voluntarily.

Comment: @Puppy - Rollback wars don't help anyone. Locking the post to stop it is the only way that's been found to work. It forces you to wait and hopefully cool down.

Comment: @ChrisF: I'm not the one trying to make something happen without discussing it with the other party. It's the other guys who should have to wait.

Comment: @Puppy - you were asked why you were rolling back the edit - you declined to answer and only gave your reasons *after* the post had been locked and then unlocked.

Comment: The system is designed to automatically start showing deleted questions to those programmatically deemed to be 'responsible' enough to see them, surely people voluntarily coming to help out with the community overrides that? Or perhaps you had no views on politics until you were deemed old enough to vote?

Comment: @Puppy I asked if a photo could be added, someone took the effort to do that. Rather than you saying in a comment you felt it shouldn't be need, you just rolled back, and again and again.

Comment: @ChrisF: Yes, I was in the middle of writing a comment and then saw that someone else edited it back again, so I paused to fix it.

Comment: @thecoshman: The question has "WRITTEN BY PUPPY" stamped all over it. Despite the fact that, when you view it, 90% of what you see was, in fact, not written by Puppy and explicitly opposed by Puppy. If "the community" is gonna take the question, *they can take the question*. As long as my name and avatar is up there, then it should be a reflection of the choices that I have made.

Comment: @Puppy Trust me, I think everyone knows at this point that you don't want the screenshot.

Comment: The question also has "edited by Mad Scientist" along with a link that shows exactly to what extent Mad Scientist changed the question. Said link also includes which parts of the question were written by Puppy.

Comment: @Puppy: _"The question has 'WRITTEN BY PUPPY' stamped all over it."_ I don't see that text even once. Could you please provide a screenshot of where you're seeing "WRITTEN BY PUPPY" "stamped all over" this question? Thanks.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: That is not enough.

Comment: Puppy..... I think you mistake SO for what it isn't... the content you post here ISN'T YOURS.  it's a community effort and has edits from other people explicitely for that reason.  I love how on one hand you say "this is not how the site was designed to be, I should not show deleted stuff to people who can't see deleted stuff" but on the other hand seem to fail at understanding how the site IS designed to be a community effort to build the best questions/answers possible, with input from EVERYONE.  The ONLY difference between before/after edit is a small screenshot.... just calm down

Comment: So much effort wasted on such an inconsequential question.

Comment: Does anyone know why this question was downvoted so extremely? Its seems like a valid question. What criteria is being used to select the downvote?

Comment: @jww Puppy is suggesting that it's fair for a user to receive 510 reputation for w̶r̶i̶t̶i̶n̶g̶ ̶t̶h̶r̶e̶e̶ ̶c̶h̶a̶r̶a̶c̶t̶e̶r̶s̶  using Unicode trickery to get around the minimum 30 characters limit for answers. It is NAA because it should be a comment

Answer (score 42):

Three - sorry four reasons.

1. It had been deleted by the OP and then undeleted by community action.
2. If the user (and subsequent editor) hadn't used Unicode shenanigans it wouldn't have passed the minimum post length test.
3. It was flagged (for the above) so it came to my attention
4. There were other answers that backed up the assertion with evidence that provided more value to the community (like how to work out there were no changes).

None of the reasons **individually** would normally convince me that the post needed to be deleted, but when taken altogether they did.

The question wasn't brilliant in the first place - being about something that could have been fairly easily found out from a search.

The first and fourth reasons were the clinchers - if the OP decided that the answer shouldn't have been posted then I saw no reason for the community to override that decision.

Comment: The answer answers the question perfectly. I have had to add waffle to answers before to get around that minimum length limit. And reason three is not a reason.

Comment: You forgot reason #0: Jefffrey ruined it.

Comment: Deep inside R.M wanted it to be undeleted.

Comment: @thecoshman - yes 3 is a reason. If it hadn't of been flagged I probably wouldn't have deleted even if I'd come across it browsing the site.

Comment: @ChrisF then you must be a bad mod. You shouldn't delete things *just* because they are flagged. Yes flagging means they probably do need some attention/deletion. So, once flagged and brought to your attention, what made you think you should indeed delete it?

Comment: Reasons #1 and #2... @thecoshman

Comment: @CodyGray and thus reason #3 is not a reason why it was deleted.

Comment: @thecoshman - I expressed myself badly. If I came across a post like this and I thought it was *doing no harm* I probably wouldn't delete. However, the minute it starts generating flags then it's causing harm and *has* to be deleted.

Comment: It was undeleted by community action *because it's a perfectly fine answer*. The answerer used Unicode shenanigans to get past the minimum length because the minimum length clearly does not apply to questions which can be perfectly well answered in two characters.

Comment: @ChrisF Kind of implies to me that I can just flag anything for deletion since it's causing some minor harm. I don't think flagging a correct answer should be grounds for deletion.

Comment: @Rapptz - nope, because if the post is not delete worthy your flag would get declined.

Comment: Do the mods have a protocol for that, if a war starts when a poster deletes their answer and the community undeletes it? Should the post be deleted and locked, undeleted and locked, disassociated from OP's account, or what?

Comment: So you deleted it because people felt butt hurt that they spent far too long writing far too much compared to that short concise answer. I didn't realise we favoured long drawn out waffly answers that never really say much, take up more space than is needed, hide subtle insults maybe about the Puppy's mother and don't add anything of real value. Maybe it's panders to the rep whores more? Maybe we just like wasting time? What type of fish do you like most? It's a shame about the overfishing of cod really. Have I made a point here about how short answers might be perfectly fine? Another comment?

Comment: @Michelle - It's not something that's flagged up to us, so no we don't have a protocol. However, in this case I noticed it because I checked the revision history and it was this that clinched my decision to delete.

Comment: Mmm, waffles. Yes, waffly answers are great.

Comment: @thecoshman - no. I deleted because the OP had used Unicode shenanigans to circumvent the minimum post length then (rightly) changed his mind had deleted the post, but the post had been resurrected against his wishes.

Comment: @thecoshman Short answers are fine - but if you can answer a question with "yes" or "no" then perhaps it's not a very good question in the first place or one that can be easily answered with a search of the web.

Comment: If the community can overrides OP's desire to post and answer, why can't it override OP's desire to delete it? Oh wait, it can...

Comment: @ChrisF Unfortunately, this is not one of those times. The question is not inherently easy to Google and you have to go through the C++ standard, compare against the old one and then answser it. It's a simple closed-ended question but it's by no means an actual terrible question with low research effort.

Comment: I have little opinion about this deletion, and your answer Chris is generally fine. However it does concern me when you assert that the OP's will about the content is more important than community consensus. Stack Exchange has always been very clear that this site is collaborative.

Comment: @Rapptz - in that case then a "No" with a link to the documentation and short explanation of how you worked that out would be the best answer.

Comment: @ChrisF: That does not make the posted answer not an answer, though. You can always add more detail to any answer.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - there were other answers that also said "no" and **backed it up with evidence** so there was really no need for that answer to exist.

Comment: @Puppy there were other answers with that additional information (reason #4)

Comment: @ChrisF Sure. But this isn't about the quality of the answer. Low quality answers are still answers and shouldn't be deleted.

Comment: This is not Skeptics. You don't have to prove everything in every answer you write. Other people posting more detailed answers does not make your answer less of an answer.

Comment: @Puppy - true most of the time. However see reason #2.

Comment: @ChrisF: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269297/why-was-this-answer-deleted#comment82043_269297

Comment: @ChrisF: _"there were other answers that also [..]"_ Yes (I have little opinion about that either way), but that's a totally different thing to what I was talking about in my comment, which you have yet to address. (Your conclusion that all four reasons in concert lead to a justified deletion is convincing.)

Comment: @ChrisF: It's not the answerer's fault that the minimum length stuff is broken.

Comment: @Puppy: What, so, "you don't like a law" = "no problem in breaking it" and "evidence of law breakage cannot be used as evidence"? _Really?_

Comment: @Puppy - that is a separate discussion.

Comment: @ChrisF: I disagree. If you're going to delete a perfectly good answer for a reason, then that reason should not be "I applied a rule that's totally inappropriate for this question just because the guys who wrote it clearly didn't think of questions like this one and therefore didn't think to make an exception".

Comment: He applied a rule that is _totally_ appropriate for this question. Now that you have your answer, perhaps just stop this madness...

Comment: So basically, you felt the answer was bad, and rather than just downvoting, you deleted. Good job!

Comment: @thecoshman - No. It was deleted (partly) because it was generating flags. If I'd down-voted it would have carried on generating flags, thus causing more work for the moderators.

Comment: @ChrisF oh, so you got fed up with others not understanding that 'bad answer' != 'raise flag'. "No", is not spam, not offensive, abusive or hate speech, it is certainly an answer, so it just need moderator attention... for what? Being too efficient? I'm curious, what exactly were those reason people gave? "I want the rep because I spent so long writing far too much, and this clever guy made a much better answer".

Comment: Why do you assume the people that flagged were the ones with longer answers?

Comment: @thecoshman This conversation isn't going anywhere. If you can come up with a system that trains people to flag correctly then you'll be a hero.

Comment: For what is worth, I did make a much better answer: it's still there, not deleted, 20+ score as of this writing. (And if you have to ask, I posted it as a separate answer instead of editing the existing one out of respect for the votes of the tens of people that had already voted on the controversial one; I wouldn't like it if my vote ended up in an answer almost, but not quite, entirely unlike the one I voted on)

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: (I'd have done the same, for the same reason.)

Comment: @ChrisF I just have problems with the fact you can't seem to provide a valid reason for deleting the answer.  All of your reasons cited here are bogus, and combining them doesn't make for that strong an argument either.

Comment: @thecoshman The first point alone seems like enough reason to me- Combining it with point four makes it pointless to keep that answer (in my opinion). If the original author of the post finds it of no value, and there are answers that explain it, I don't see how that answer is worth keeping around. Could you provide a better explanation for why it _should_ be kept around despite just those two points? It would better help me understand your side of this debate, and may help others see it as well.

Comment: @Kendra well, you are only look at the first half of point one, missing the second part, were it was undeleted by the community, meaning it was felt worth keeping already. I agree that compared to the other answer, 'no' it not much worth, but why delete it? We have votes to hide answer that are felt not worth keeping. Last I was aware, deleting was not for 'bad answers', it was for spam, offensive or simple 'not an answer' answers.

Comment: @thecoshman What I've noticed from other meta discussions (I unfortunately don't have the time to scare one up and verify) is that if it does not add any information to the post, it's not necessarily worth keeping around. I could have interpreted this incorrectly, of course, but just "No!" adds nothing to what the other answers have said, so that would make it not worth keeping around correct? And yes, community undeleted it, but my point was that the _author_ doesn't want it around- It's their name associated with it. Doesn't that matter here?

Comment: @Kendra well, I'm not sure about timing, but I think this answer was posted early on. Besides, no, if that author doesn't want to be associated with it they should post it, or they can make it CW if they wish.

Comment: @thecoshman CWing it would just disassociate the rep. Their name is still on it. It's still there to see. And I'm not sure about the timing either- I haven't opened the question in a bit- But that shouldn't really matter too much in deciding the value of an answer compared to others, should it? (I'm not trying to actively argue- Just see your side. I see ChrisF's side clear enough. Yours is a bit foggier to me.)

Answer (score 14):

Without an explanation, this answer ("**No!**") may become useless in case if someone else posts an opposite opinion.

For example, if someone posts a claim like **"Yes!"**, how would this answer help reader to pick of two opposing opinions?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mOFCT.png]

Comment: I'm not sure that this explains why the answer should be *deleted* rather than just downvoted with extreme prejudice. It shows why the answer is poor, but not why it's unacceptable.

Comment: @Michelle downvoting "with extreme prejudice" sounds like a nice idea... when one ignores that people vote as they wish (and [not by idealistic meta rules](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/01/the-trouble-with-popularity/ "see eg The Trouble With Popularity")). Consider re-checking [screen shot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eXT6v.png) of deleted answer, it shows score +51, how many downvotes would you want to offset this? 52?

Comment: ...to avoid misunderstanding, I am not against downvotes in general (qualifying for 4-5 [Pale Horse Rider](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/135010/165773 "5000 downvotes on posts that were later deleted") badges, why would I). It's just that downvotes don't always work

Comment: By my understanding poor answers that aren't spam/offensive/NAA should not be deleted by the community/mods, just downvoted. Has there been any discussion on what to do with poor quality answers that get heavily upvoted anyway?

Comment: @Michelle given that question is in hot list (4K views in a day), I would consider classical guidance given by Jeff Atwood in [How aggressively should we maintain and improve very popular questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/103069/165773)

Comment: @gnat: _"Consider re-checking screen shot of deleted answer, it shows score +51, how many downvotes would you want to offset this? 52?"_ You seem to be suggesting that one person should be able to completely cancel out the opinion of _fifty-two other people_ just because _they_ have a different opinion. You've shown such draconian thinking in the past. Do you not understand the concept of group decision-making?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I just follow thinking laid out in [The Trouble With Popularity](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/01/the-trouble-with-popularity/): "This is why community moderators have real power; they _need_ that power to intervene, educate, and refocus the community’s exuberance on more substantive content..." And if you wanna play numbers, consider taking into account [600+ votes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/171543/165773) given to that "single person" in election

Comment: @gnat damn you... now my head hurts thinking about that voting system :S

Comment: @gnat: [You're not the first to think about this problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/96226/155739).

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit `f(Number_Of_Question_Views)` in your formula makes me feel that adjusted score for that "answer" would be somewhere between 5 and 0.5 (at 4K views of the question). I wonder by the way why you propose linear transformation, and not, say, logarithmic

Comment: @gnat: Logarithmic might be a good idea

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that it was a problematic answer.  No other answer posted on that question were as quick and easy to read and understand as the deleted answer.

That being said, there were other answers on that question that essentially conveyed the same answer, that there are no new keywords in c++ 14.  The OP apparently believed his post to be obsolete, so he deleted it.

And the OP was right, it was obsolete. Even though it's an easy to read answer, it was still surrounded by other answers, and since bringing it back wouldn't clear away those other answers, it wouldn't make the information more easy to find for future users anyway.

So when other people voted to un-delete the answer, the Mod came and deleted it again, and since the OP would have had it deleted in the first place, there's no real harm done.

Answer (score 1):

Is it really fair for a user to receive 510 reputation for <s>writing *three* characters</s> using Unicode trickery to get around the minimum 30 characters limit for answers?

The post is NAA because it should be a comment (but it turns out it is even too short to be a comment).

And *look at the comments on the answer!* They totally agree with my points:

[image: comments on deleted answer]

User @nneonneo emphasises the Unicode misconduct by posting an empty comment using the same characters used by the OP of the answer.

@Shahar's comment was posted probably when the answer had only 15 upvotes, but sadly that increased to 51(!).