# The rep history shows over 500 rep in one day, even though there are no accepts

Tags: bug, reputation, deleted-answers, daily-reputation-limit

Inevitably, [this happened](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/269297/46642).

Somehow that caused this:

[image]

With the rep cap at 200, this makes absolutely no sense. It did make sense before that. I had ~200 rep yesterday and another ~200 today. Now it makes no sense.

Two weird things: according to that upvotes on one answer keep on giving rep up to 352 points; and two of those upvotes were only worth 6 points. The answer that exhibits these weird votes is the one that was deleted.

Compare that with what I see in porn mode, which looks perfectly ok:

[image]

Comment: Please go over to the other question if you have something to add to that trainwreck. Not here.

Comment: I think the temporary addition of the [tantrum](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tantrum) tag to that post was humorously appropriate.

Comment: Trying so hard to process these numbers and come up with a possible scenario... Hold on, my brain is overloading- Oh, and it crashed. On a more serious note, I was going to suggest bounty, but with the -510 that doesn't make sense, and I'm sure you'd know if you had earned a bounty.

Comment: @Kendra I didn't expand it on the screenshot because, well, it's some 70 events total, but you can open my profile and expand it live to see the details (http://stackoverflow.com/users/46642/r-martinho-fernandes?tab=reputation). There are no bounties, only up- and downvotes.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes Actually, I went to your profile to see before posting the comment. The numbers aren't extreme there- And there's certainly no `-202` showing for today- I only see +170 on your profile today. Hence the brain crash.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: I cannot see your -510 and +352 if I look at your rep

Comment: In fact, I don't see a single downvote for today, yesterday, or 2 days ago.

Comment: Also, assuming they are really there... why -510? You had 57 upvotes on that answer

Comment: @musefan I was assuming it was some odd kinda of serial reversal but I don't think it could even remotely hit 510. So it's hard to say.

Comment: Wow, that *is* weird. I'll post an expanded screenshot after I  fix my WiFi.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes for comparison sake, consider opening your rep tab in anonymous / not logged in browser mode, that way you will see what other users see there. Content displayed to profile owner differs from one shown to others (otherwise people could see `-1`s at whose answers you voted down which would break anonymous voting). I for example see 200 for today and 201 for yesterday in [your rep tab](http://stackoverflow.com/users/46642/r-martinho-fernandes?tab=reputation)

Comment: Added screenshots.

Comment: ahaha, robot broke the system. :)

Comment: What exactly do you mean by the last sentence?

Comment: @derp Isn't that the only reason to use incognito/in-private browsing? ;)

Answer (score 8):

I believe I figured out what has happened here.

Without being able to investigate much deeper and just by running a little math:

Yesterday: You see +543. We see +201.
The only bit we don't see from yesterday is `+352/-10`.
Let's do a little math:

`543 - 352 = 191   191 + 10 = 201`

The math adds up and makes sense of what we see. Good. Now let's look at today (as of your posting screenshots) and do some more math.

You see -142. We see +200.
Here, we don't see the `-510` or the `+170/-2`.

`-142 + 510 = 368  368 - 170 = 198   198 + 2 = 200`

Considering the events that are hitting at the same time here, I think it can be assumed by most users that this happened:

1. You wrote the post. Got upvoted.
2. You decided the post wasn't worth it and deleted.
3. You got up to the rep cap without the rep from the deleted post.
4. Community undeleted, you regained the rep, throwing you far over the cap for yesterday.
5. Today, a mod deleted the post again. This resulted in the `-510` and reset things to how they should've been if the post had not been undeleted.

Of course, this would mean that there could be an issue with undeleting restoring rep lost through deleting *above the rep cap.* If this is the case, I would assume it is indeed a bug, but we'd have to hear from the team to both verify my guess is correct and to verify if this is intended behavior.

The other possible issue, as pointed out by Servy (and probably much more likely), is there is a bug in how the reputation is displayed, but the extra rep might not have been re-added to the account.

Comment: It's almost certainly a bug in *how the daily reputation changes are displayed on the profile*.  It's far less likely that it's a bug in how the actual reputation changes are applied to the account.

Comment: True- Unless of course if the question had remained undeleted and that rep-gain had stayed. The answer itself was posted yesterday, all the votes were gained yesterday and this morning. So if deleting, hitting rep cap, and undeleting would give you far more rep than allowed by the cap, that would be a bug. Of course, that is still just a guess at what happened.

Comment: That logic assumes that the actual change in reputation yesterday was +543, rather than it actual being 200 with the profile incorrectly stating that the reputation change yesterday was 543.

Comment: @Servy Ah, now I see what you mean. Yes, I agree- You have a point. Either way, at least this could explain why it shows what it does, even if the rep itself did not get reapplied.