# How can you find out that an answer is very low quality?

Tags: discussion, flags, answers, low-quality-posts

I have trouble distinguishing ***Very Low Quality*** answers. I was randomly checking my flagging history, and I saw that [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32933341/blocking-users-access-of-3rd-party-sites-from-my-website/32933377#32933377) which I had thought was an obvious example of ***VLQ*** posts, not only was not deleted, but to my astonishment, it was complimented and upvoted.

Now, OP has modified his answer, the original answer was:

> **NO**, fortunately, you cannot do that.

Do you have any reasoning why people consider it a good post?

**My thought:**

People who has read the question probably said:

> What a dumb question! How on earth doesn't he know ***the obvious***?

Scrolling down, they relieved when an answer was shortly addressing ***the obvious***, they said:

> Straight forward. to the point. I like. I like.

And upvoted it.

I think that they have missed the point that the questioner actually *does not know **the obvious***. He is here to understand it and I have doubt that he is ever more informed after reading that lovely straight forward answer.

I can not imagine visiting a website full of that sort of straight forward answers more than once, but, I do visit SO daily because, there are a lot of nice people who explain ***the obvious*** and make it ***obvious*** to me too.

Comment: No is a perfectly acceptable answer.

Comment: @TinyGiant I have no objection to this conclusion, I simply do not know why

Comment: Actually it's at best mediocre... It should include useful reasoning. Just because it's correct, doesn't mean it's good.

Comment: @TinyGiant I would answer it `No, because ....`

Comment: It does not have severe content or formatting problems. Therefore a Very Low Quality flag is not appropriate. If you don't like content, you should downvote it.

Comment: @TinyGiant. I think down-voting is not appropriate because it is a correct answer. Down-voting signals it may be incorrect

Comment: The downvote tooltip says "This answer is not useful". If you think an answer is not useful, downvoting is entirely appropriate. What is not appropriate is flagging a correct answer with no content or formatting problems for deletion because you think it is not useful.

Comment: related: [Why was this answer deleted?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/269297/839601)

Comment: It's a terrible answer, mainly because there is no explanation to it, but it's not worthy of flagging. I would just downvote and move on.

Comment: I think sometimes (although not often) "No" can even be a high quality answer if it can answer the question correctly, for example, if the reason is not important, not interesting or even in the case that most people would not aware the reason. If explaining it may be noise I would rather prefer "No" without explaination.

Comment: @amuse **Especially** when people are not aware of the reason it is a good idea to explain it. An explanation is never noise (given that it is correct). The worst it can do is make an answer better. Agreed, not all answers require an explanation, but it will never hurt anyone

Comment: I'm the author of **the answer** and I've updated it with, some how, a proper explanation.

Comment: I can't even type "Less is more" here without seeing "3 more to go..."

Comment: Sometimes, low quality answers are the result of low quality questions. That problem has been solved now…

Comment: Less = More​​​​

Answer (score 46):

Well the easiest way is to look at the VLQ description in the flag dialog and analyze the answer based on the criteria in it.

> This answer has severe formatting or content problems. This answer is unlikely to be salvageable through editing, and might need to be removed.

Does the answer have any formatting problems? No.

Does it have any content problem? Well, it's short, but it answers the question - just doesn't use many words to do it. So no.

Just because an answer is short doesn't mean it should be deleted. Sure, they could explain *why* it's not possible, and that would make their answer a whole lot better. But not explaining doesn't make it trash. If you think the answer isn't useful without an explanation, then that's what downvotes are for.

Comment: Well, on [Is “this is not possible” an acceptable answer?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261168), consensus seems to be that an "impossible"-answer should not just say no, it should elaborate just like any other answer. In [Should I flag answers consisting only of “No” or “Yes”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/110165) on MSE all but the newest (and lowest-scoring) answer advocate flagging, that one recommending downvotes (it got upvotes instead!).

Comment: @animuson What do you say about this: http://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/8627062

Comment: @Deduplicator That's quite true, but an answer that fails to provide a sufficient information is simply a bad answer, and one that should be downvoted.  It doesn't mean that the answer merits deletion, even though it's not a good answer.

Answer (score 8):

Very low quality is posts that are completely crap. It almost always referring to answers, since questions have the close vote mechanism.

Very low quality, as defined by SO, includes things like:

- The OP posting further details to the question as an answer, instead of using edit on the question. (Posting an answer to your own question is fine though.)
- Answers that do nothing but asking the OP for more details - should have been comments.
- Any form of rambling that doesn't attempt to answer the question, including attempts to "bump" the question to get more attention.
- "I'm having this problem too" posted as answers, including someone else's similar problem, without providing a solution.
- Questions posted as answers.
- Link-only answers.
- Spam.

All such posts should be deleted.

It is important to realize the difference between the above and answers that are merely bad:

- If an answerer makes an attempt to actually answer the question, it is not "very low quality" per SO definition. It should not get flagged/deleted.
- "Very low quality" does not concern itself with the contents of the answer, apart from the special case of link-only answers. A simple "no it is not possible" is a perfectly valid answer. Perhaps not a good one, but still valid.
- If the contents of the answer are bad or technically incorrect, the answer should get down-voted, not deleted.

Comment: +1 especially for the last three points: just because you think an answer is bad doesn't make it VLQ.

Comment: Sorry, but all but spam in your first list is not VLQ but NAA, and the last is SPAM.

Comment: @Lundin How do you explain this: http://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/8627062

Comment: @Deduplicator It is really just the same crap. My examples come from what typically ends up in the very low quality review queue.

Comment: @Ormoz That's a harsh review. Main reason you failed is because the review audits are rather broken, picking randomly deleted answers for the audit, even when the answer wasn't deleted because of low-quality. As for the specifics of that particular answer, it is a tough call. Answers that go like "have you tried...", "I'm guess it could be..." are in the borderline between answers and comments. Answers should be certain, otherwise they are better posted as comments.

Comment: @Ormoz You failed that audit because the post is not an answer, it's a comment.

Comment: @Lundin A bunch of your VLQ qualifiers are actually NaA qualifiers instead.

Comment: @Deduplicator Yes, and there's an automated comment for each of these 'not VLQ but NAA' under the 'Should be Deleted' button...

Comment: @Lundin if we reword "Try xxx" to "In some cases it helps to xxx", does it make the answer any better?

Comment: @JanDvorak Not much, either suggests "I don't know how to solve this, yet I posted an answer." Unless of course the meaning of "some cases" are explicitly listed, then it is a much better answer.

Answer (score 3):

As explained by @Animuson, this one does not fit in VLQ definition.

But I must admit that (before last edits that make it now a really correct answer) I would have left a comment saying that no without any explaination is acceptable for a comment, but not for an answer.

So my opinion is that the answer should have been flagged as Not An Answer (just a comment) **with a comment for the poster** to advise him to add an explaination (what has now been done).

Comment: Even before such an edit the answer isn't Not An Answer.  It's arguably a bad answer, and you can downvote an answer that you think is lacking sufficient explanation, but it's not Not An Answer.

Comment: @Servy: thanks. I was at *did it try to answer* and honestly did not think it did. I'll now be more strict in my flag attempts :-)

Answer (score -4):

*“Very Low Quality answers”* would be better worded as *“Not an Answer”*.

There is **no way** that someone looking at the “answer” that knows nothing about the subject can consider that it **may** adds any **value** whatever.  For example

- I got the same problem
- Don’t be so daft
- Thank you

Comment: So, you are saying the VLQ-flag is completely redundant?

Comment: I disagree. VLQ is not the same as NAA. NAA is a comment; VLQ is something you would downvote into oblivion without a second thought because it's just _so_ bad and misses the point and is in like ten different languages with broken links and corrupted images. But was still effectively an attempt at answering.

Comment: As far as I can tell, they end up in the same low quality review queue. I don't really see why we need to name crap in so many different ways. A rose by any other name...

Comment: @Lundin the flags are handled differently at the mod review queue level. A moderator may decline a VLQ flag on a post where they would mark an NaA flag helpful.

Comment: @TinyGiant Since they end up in the user low-quality review queues, there's no difference. Again, there is no need to come up with 50 different names for crap. (Particularly, there's no need to come up with home brewed abbreviations for them...) Either the post is so bad that it needs to be deleted, or it is not.

Comment: @Deduplicator plenty of people are saying the VLQ flag is completely redundant.

Comment: @TinyGiant, so VLQ flags _are_ inherently broken?

Comment: Not all of the flags are handled in the user queues, any VLQ/NaA flags on answers that become accepted before exiting the queue (same with VLQ questions with accepted answers). Even if it gets six deletion votes, it still ends up in a moderator queue and the moderator may chose a different outcome than those in the review queues. If a post sits in a user queue for longer than a day, it gets sent to the moderator queue. The flags themselves are not redundant, both being lumped into one queue is unfortunate, but they do not mean the same thing. @Lundin

Comment: @JanDvorak see above.