# What to do if an NAA flag for a three words answer was declined?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags

I had flagged [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4083239/proper-way-to-initialize-a-string-in-c/4083256#4083256) answer as it should not be an answer, and instead be a comment as it has only three words, and does not answer the question properly:

> both are valid.

I cannot understand that how can this be a proper answer, and thus flagged it. It got declined, and the message the moderator declining it wrote:

[image]

Well, I know that this flag got declined because of some reason, which I could not understand.

My main question is what I should do now? Should I reflag the answer as I do not think that this should be declined, or should I just edit the answer, or whatever else. Also, could someone een explain the reason of this flag being declined.

**NOTE:** Do not flag it as a duplicate to those questions that ask should we flag a one-liner answer, as I am asking what to do if it gets declined.

Comment: You flagged it as NAA, but it is an answer.  You shouldn't reflag it or edit it.  You can post your own answer, if you want to improve it or correct it.

Comment: @PetahChristian, yes it is an answer, but it shows that the user has put no effort answering the question, and in fact should be a comment.

Comment: So you're insinuating that we should keep it in the form of a comment? How is that better than just deleting it outright?

Comment: @AshishAhuja "yes it is an answer" **Then don't flag it as not an answer**, and don't be surprised when it's declined, telling you that it is in fact an answer.  The fact that there is no effort in it doesn't make it a comment.  Comments aren't the place that you put bad answers.  Answers get posted as answers, regardless of quality. If you think it's a bad answer, downvote it.

Comment: That is 100% an answer to that question, and I don't just mean in the absurd ["*attempts* to answer the question like an inline image of Milla Jovovich" sense](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/308441/176646). The question is "which of these two is correct" and the short answer is "both are."

Comment: @BoltClock, by deleting the answer, the content in it will be gone. Keeping it as an comment will be right, as such content might be useful, but in the form of comments, not answers.

Comment: @AshishAhuja Again, comments aren't the place that we put bad answers.  If it's an answer, it's appropriate that it's posted as an answer.  If it's a bad answer, downvote it.  Comments are for requests for clarification, responses to other posts, and other things that *aren't even answers at all*.

Comment: How can a zero-effort answer (as you say) contain any useful content? That's an oxymoron.

Comment: @BoltClock, it matters if the content is gone. The answer is not answering the question, but providing some hints. That answer does contain useful hints.

Comment: @AshishAhuja But it *is* answering the question, *as you said yourself earlier*.  It is not providing a *hint*.  It's providing an answer.  It's just providing a poorly explained answer.

Comment: Now you're just contradicting yourself. First you say "yes it is an answer", and now you say that it's not answering the question. Which one is it? (IMO "both are valid." *does* answer the question of "which of these is valid?")

Comment: see also: [Why was this answer deleted?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/269297/839601)

Comment: @BoltClock can we have an actual guideline of what can be defined as an answer what can't? The definition of when it is or when it isn't lives in a very grayish area.

Comment: The guideline is, does it attempt to answer the question. Like, if you read it, is there an answer there? "I have this problem too" is not an answer. Neither are joke posts, or memes, rants, or "thank you"s. The subjective part is not whether something is an answer, it's whether something is a *good* answer. That's okay, you use votes to determine that, not flags. @just

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The post is an answer to the question.  It's a *bad* answer, but it is *an answer*.  If you think an answer is bad, you downvote it.  If a post *isn't an answer at all* then you flag it.

> Also, could someone explain the reason of this flag being declined.

It's declined because the post is an answer, and you shouldn't flag posts for being wrong or just bad answers, as the decline reason is telling you.

Comment: I agree with you that it is a bad answer, so what should I do with it?

Comment: Read my answer to find out.  I tell you exactly what you should do if you think an answer is bad.