# Was moderation action against this short answer justified?

Tags: discussion, moderation, specific-answer

There was a short (2-sentence) question asked which got a short answer:

1. the first iteration of the answer said "**No**" (with some non-printable characters to fit the minimum character limit)
2. the answer was a bit later edited so that the text was a link which pointed to the answer itself (presumably for additional tongue-in-cheek character).

Note that "no" is a clear and correct answer to the short question (the question is of the form "*Can I do [thing] without [obvious prerequisite]?*").

An hour later delete-from-review autocomments started appearing, claiming that

1. the answer is link-only, and
2. the answer is not an answer.

Neither claims are correct, so I argued a bit with one of the reviewers and flagged both auto-comments as no longer needed (the LQP review item got 4 unanimous "recommend deletion" votes, but the positive score of the answer stopped the review process).

A bit later my comment flags were marked helpful, but the comments stayed, and ChrisF deleted the answer and left the following comment:

> Mark this as a duplicate rather than posting a link to another answer. – ChrisF♦

What ChrisF didn't do is close the question as the duplicate of another question...since there *is no* duplicate question; the link in the answer was self-referential. I assumed that the moderator misread something so I left a custom moderator flag:

> The moderator who handled this post seems to have made a grave mistake. They deleted this answer claiming that the answerer should post it on the duplicate instead rather than linking there. The mod didn't close the question as duplicate. One reason for this is that the link was pointing to this very answer. Yes, it's tongue-in-cheek, but it was an answer, and the link didn't point anywhere. The answer should not have been deleted with this reasoning. Please fix it. Thank you.

This is now

> declined - The post is way too far off base. A joke link violates the Be Nice policy, and given that there is a better more complete answer I see no reason to resurrect this.

(The "more complete answer" basically says "*No, unless you have [prerequisite].*".)

**tl;dr** 4 reviewers and a moderator mistook a tongue-in-cheek yet valid answer as something else, or something inappropriate.

Is this simply a corollary of us hating fun? The question was obviously misguided in the sense that just "No" is a perfectly valid answer. Do/should we ignore the grossly wrong review decisions and the seemingly contradictory mod deletion because of the self-link in the answer? Is such an answer really Not Nice?

---

Correction: BoltClock [made me aware](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/364977/was-moderation-action-against-this-short-answer-justified#comment567646_364977) that the link in the answer wasn't intentionally self-referential, it only turned out that way by mistake. The URL looks like a link to a comment made by another user on the question, but the ID in the link is replaced by that of the answer, thereby redirecting readers to the answer itself. The corresponding comment on the question explains that the question is somewhat nonsense to begin with.

Comment: [Yes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/364977/was-moderation-action-against-this-short-answer-justified#comment567609_364977).

Comment: See also: [Is 'don't do it' a valid answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8891/is-dont-do-it-a-valid-answer)

Comment: @JoshCaswell thanks. Though that doesn't seem to be the same scenario; the question and answer seem more along the lines of "Don't do what you're asking about, do this instead: [idiomatic solution]". The one I'm talking about is "Can I do [impossible thing]?" -> "No".

Comment: I'd say a "No" answer should always be a "No, because XYZ" answer. Answers without explanation are not very likely to help future visitors.

Comment: The situations are analogous. As BDL said, "No" is not sufficient. It needs to be "No, [and here's why]".

Comment: @BDL: ... which is a reason to downvote, not delete.

Comment: The link isn't even self-referential. The link actually points to a comment on the question. However, because it contains the answer ID, the site silently replaces the comment hash with the answer ID hash, so the viewer gets redirected to the answer instead of the comment. (I'm not sure if I'd consider this a bug, but it's definitely surprising and counterproductive behavior that probably should be changed.)

Comment: Of course, if the answer was intended to be a reference to that comment, because the comment happens to be the answer to the question that for some reason was not posted as one, then were the answerer making a serious attempt to answer the question they should have just quoted the comment and given due credit. The fact that they not only didn't the first time, but thinks that the content isn't essential enough to warrant putting into the answer, insofar that were it to break, the flat "No." would still be sufficient to answer the question, makes me question if it was even posted in good faith.

Comment: That, of course, is my reason not to resurrect the answer, not my reason to delete it to begin with. Don't get me wrong, I think this could have been handled far better. For example, I would have readily deleted the answer had it been custom-flagged with something like "Answerer does not seem to be acting in good faith; <context as to why>"

Comment: @JoshCaswell I am so disappointed that you posted that as a comment instead of an answer.

Comment: bottom line what you're all saying is just: "SO hates fun". Personally, I think it's a shame.

Comment: @BoltClock thanks for the comment link, I completely missed that. I'll take a closer look later and update the question.

Comment: related: [Why was this answer deleted?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/269310/839601)

Comment: I mean if you're going to answer "no" then you might as well make it less pretentious and answer "not likely" instead. But it all depends on the question too; sometimes "no" is just a polite way of saying "you've got to be kidding me".

Comment: @shai its not so much that we hate fun, its more that on the main site cheekiness/humor can seriously backfire. People are looking for serious answers and so start to take things seriously which [they absolutely shouldn't](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/364961/424903).

Comment: @Gimby "Not likely" would have been a wrong answer. "No" was, indeed, the only correct answer. And while it was tongue in cheek, the "No" linked to an explanation.

Comment: "No, you are completely wrong" can be **part** of a valid answer. But a "No, you are completely wrong. It's impossible to XYZ." looked like a valid answer, even without an explanation.

Comment: @AnderBiguri the post did not link to an explanation, it linked to itself as per the problem description.

Comment: @AnderBiguri attempted to link to a comment, but failed. In any case no need to rehash all that BoltClock has already stated (which I wish was in an answer). No wasn't an answer, any more than "not likely" is without an explanation. Answers need to be verifiable, just bluntly stating "no" is just one person's experience. Okay, good to know that you can't do it, we all have our limitations. But what would be the reason that absolutely nobody will be able to do it? "Because I can't do it" is not a valid reason.

Comment: @Gimby Don't want to get into a discussion, but the answer is "No, because of the fundamental principles of mathematics", which OP would probably somehow know if they would have googled a bit. I understand why this was deleted. But also "SO hates fun", which is sad :(

Comment: @AnderBiguri "SO hates fun" is wrong but fun is something that has to be interpreted correctly, depending on social background and cultural behaviour...

Comment: Disclosure: I declined your flag, that last message is mine. I missed that the link was not supposed to be a self-link there. I was also rather irked that you felt the need to call the moderator action a *grave mistake* for a post that only said *No* with a link, which could have affected my ability to give the post more attention. Your flag may have gotten a better response if you had kept some perspective.

Comment: Thanks, @Martijn, I hadn't considered that. The graveness was regarding the apparent deletion based on a duplicate claim, which was clearly wrong. The combination of helpful comment flags on mistaken review autocomments with the comments sticking around didn't help either. Not an excuse, just an explanation for the lack of perspective on my part. I'll try to be more objective in my future flags (as I usually do).

Comment: I don't think "SO hates fun" is correct.  A more accurate (and meaningful) characterization is that many >>people<< reading SO, either are humorless or in a bad mood, or don't understand the joke for language or cultural reasons, or are offended because they interpret the humor as mocking >>them<<.  And on the last point, being the subject of mockery is something that is difficult for some people ... depending on their culture.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

OK. I could have handled this better.

I saw that it was a link to page on SO but I didn't double check the exact link - my bad - so I assumed that it was a link to another question. Hence my comment about flagging/voting to close the question as a duplicate.

As for not closing it as a duplicate - I don't do that unless I'm 100% sure as my vote is binding. I leave the comment to encourage the answerer to use the system correctly.

However, it still needed deleting as it wasn't an answer.

If the original commentator wasn't prepared to expand their comment into a fully fledged answer then there's nothing stopping you doing that (with appropriate references).

Just posting a link with the word "No" and having to include non-printing text to get above the minimum length threshold shows bad faith at best and trolling behaviour at worst.

If you're going to answer a question provide an actual answer, not a link to something else that may or may not be still around when someone tries to click on it.

Comment: Thanks for your perspective. I guess the situation is a bit different with a (broken) link to a comment, but this is something I hadn't originally realized.

Comment: I have seen questions where the answer "no" is totally appropriate, and I really resent editorial busy-bodies who think they know better.

Comment: @MichaelKay Then the question is probably bad. [Or not](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/873d8d4c-45af-4669-a2f9-56e02ec75dae/view-source).

Answer (score -2):

Generally speaking "No" is not a good SO answer, and the minimal character limit is indeed appropriate.

**However**, sometimes, on very rare occasions, "NO" is a valid and good answer:
When your son is asking you "Can I stick my finger into the fire?" you usually answer "NO!!" and do not dwell into a physical explanation of what is fire and how it may affect the molecular structure of his finger.
Or, when a user asks a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49423239/1714410): a straight forward and clear "NO" is a valid answer.

I am a SO member for over 5 years now with close to [2000 answers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1714410/shai?tab=answers). When I write "rare occasions" it translates to roughly one in a thousand (!) answers. I must say I was a little disappointed with the way SO community handled this issue.

Comment: Well then... yes, it's useful for the OP, but other users will find the explanation useful. [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4196860/).

Answer (score -12):

An answer "with tongue-in-cheek" is very bad for StackOverflow as you have many readers from different cultural areas at StackOverflow.

What one thinks is an humorous answer can be offending to another user, therefore "humor" is discouraged on StackOverflow, because it could be misinterpreted or misleading.

Also a short answer like "No" is discouraged and should have at least a short explanation.

Therefore I can fully understand that such an answer was deleted.